# Android passing R.String.xx value to string builder

Tags: android, stringbuilder

string value to the string builder but i am unable to get the value

```
builder.append("<tr align=center bgcolor=#9d8a2e><th colspan=2 height="
                        + tableHeight
                        + " width="
                        + tableWidthLeft
                        + **R.string.useonly**
                        + "</th><th align=right  height="
                        + tableHeight
                        + " width="
                        + tableWidthRight
                        + ">"
                        + Provider.im_rad + "" + "</th></tr>");
```

i am suppose to pass **R.string.useonly**  but it is not working.....but when i do this as below it is working

```
builder.append("<tr align=center bgcolor=#9d8a2e><th colspan=2 height="
                        + tableHeight
                        + " width="
                        + tableWidthLeft
                        + ">for use only purpose"
                        + "</th><th align=right  height="
                        + tableHeight
                        + " width="
                        + tableWidthRight
                        + ">"
                        + Provider.im_rad+ "" + "</th></tr>");
```

Comment: try this `getResources().getString(R.string.useonly);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Use this : [getString(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int))**

```
 builder.append("<tr align=center bgcolor=#9d8a2e><th colspan=2 height="
                    + tableHeight
                    + " width="
                    + tableWidthLeft
                    + getResources().getString(R.string.useonly))
                    + "</th><th align=right  height="
                    + tableHeight
                    + " width="
                    + tableWidthRight
                    + ">"
                    + Provider.im_rad + "" + "</th></tr>");
```

Comment: sorry it worked by giving ">"+"getResources().getString(R.string.useonly)", you were right

Answer (score 3):

To get string resource you shoud use

```
getResources().getString(R.string.your_text);
```

if you call it on fragment you should add getActivity() in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

You can get the String for the resource ID by calling on a `Context` (like the `Activity`) [`getString(resId)`.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int))